# syntaxerror: 'return' outside function in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is something wrong with my python code. I am a beginner in python.

```
def gen_qr_text(acc_id,amount):
    pp_acc_id = ""
    pp_amount = ""
    pp_chksum = ""

if len(acc_id) == 15:
    pp_acc_id = "0315" + acc_id
elif acc_id.length() == 13:
    pp_acc_id = "0213" + acc_id
elif acc_id.length() == 10:
    pp_acc_id = "01130066" + acc_id.substring(1)
else:
    return "null"

if not amount:
    pp_amount = format("54%02d%s", amount.length(), amount)

    pp_str = "00020101021129370016A000000677010111"
    + pp_acc_id
    + "5303764"
    + pp_amount
    + "5802TH"
    + "6304"
    pp_chksum = crc16.checksum(pp_str);
    pp_str += pp_chksum;
    return pp_str
```

Error says it's `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`. What's the problem with this code. By the way i convert the code from java to python. Is that everything okey in my code? I edit my code here but still there are some error

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Please indent your code we can't know which `return` statement is throwing the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly indent your code. From your question I'm guessing this would resolve your issue:

```
    import crc16

    def gen_qr_text(acc_id,amount):
        pp_acc_id = ""
        pp_amount = ""
        pp_chksum = ""

        if len(acc_id) == 15:
          pp_acc_id = "0315" + acc_id
        elif acc_id.length() == 13:
          pp_acc_id = "0213" + acc_id
        elif acc_id.length() == 10:
          pp_acc_id = "01130066" + acc_id.substring(1)
        else:
          return "null"

        if not amount:
          pp_amount = format("54%02d%s", amount.length(), amount)

        pp_str = "00020101021129370016A000000677010111" + pp_acc_id + "5303764" + pp_amount + "5802TH" + "6304"
        pp_chksum = crc16.checksum(pp_str);
        pp_str += pp_chksum;
        return pp_str
```

Comment: Yes, its almost done but something error "pp_chksum = crc16.checksum(pp_str);" in this line. Can you help me out to calculate crc16 with checksum in that line?

Comment: undefined name 'crc16'

Comment: you need to import that module `import crc16`

Answer (score 2):

Python is what is called "whitespace-sensitive": it matters how stuff is indented. For example, it expects the contents inside an `if`-clause to be indented *below* that statement:

```
if True or False:
    execute_this_function()
```

This will not work:

```
if True or False:
execute_this_function()
```

The same applies to `return` statements: they should be inside the function they apply to, i.e. that you are returning from:

```
def my_method():
    return True
```

Again, this will not work and raise the error you are getting:

```
def my_method():
return True
```

Thus, the solution is to make sure your `return`s are indented correctly. Of course, the same applies to the rest of the code!

**Edit** Based on the modification of your OP, this is the indentation you require; I also fixed the `.length()` you copied over from Java, it seems:

```
def gen_qr_text(acc_id,amount):
    pp_acc_id = ""
    pp_amount = ""
    pp_chksum = ""

    if len(acc_id) == 15:
        pp_acc_id = "0315" + acc_id
    elif len(acc_id) == 13:
        pp_acc_id = "0213" + acc_id
    elif len(acc_id) == 10:
        pp_acc_id = "01130066" + acc_id.substring(1)
    else:
        return "null"

    if not amount:
        pp_amount = format("54%02d%s", len(amount), amount)

        pp_str = "00020101021129370016A000000677010111"
        + pp_acc_id
        + "5303764"
        + pp_amount
        + "5802TH"
        + "6304"
        pp_chksum = crc16.checksum(pp_str);
        pp_str += pp_chksum;
        return pp_str
```

Comment: `True or False` that's a strange example.

Comment: Not as strange as `True and False`.

Comment: I'm not sure if he wants the rest of the code after assigning `pp_amount` indented. I figured the reason he's checking is to reassign `pp_amount` . But I could be wrong.

Comment: That through me off as well. Along with all the `.length()`s